# I invite someone on the outlook calendar it does not show up on their calendar unless they accept or decline it from there email

Tags: javascript, calendar, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-calendar

I want to show all the outlook calendar events on my custom page that we are trying to build using microsoft graph apis. But the problem is when someone invites me for an event it does not show up in the event list unless I accept/decline it. On the google calendar we see all events no matter they are accepted or declined. Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Mail Flow rule that will automatically accept meeting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/mail-flow-rules/use-rules-to-add-meetings Outlook itself has a tentative accept feature but that requires the client to be open https://www.msoutlook.info/question/do-not-automatically-accept-meeting-as-tentative